# SQL Server silent installation does not work Using InstallShield 2010

Tags: sql-server, installation

I need to install SQL Server Express 2008 silently without any user interaction Using InstallShield 2010
I am using this code but an error message appears.
Code :
`SQLEXPR_x86_ENU /q /Action=Install /Hideconsole /Features=SQL,Tools /InstanceName=SQLExpress /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="Builtin\Administrators" /SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" /SQLSVCPASSWORD="MiraSoft2016" /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6g6dY.jpg)

Please any help...

Comment: Microsoft stopped offering mainstream support for SQL Server 2008 back in 2014 and it reached end-of-life in 2019. You should ask MiraSoftAccounting to supply a version of their software that uses a more modern version of SQL Server.

Comment: That *looks* like you trying to install that onto Windows 10 or server equivilent? SQL Server 2008 doesn't work on Windows 10; it's too old. Use a supported version of SQL Server.

Comment: I know that but I want to install it silently where is the problem!!